# eclipse library imports jar file issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have a eclipse related question which maybe someone could help me with. I have download and extracted a library from github and want to import it into my application. It gives you two test applications with the library. I make new projects from the existing file systems in eclipse but the two sample projects have a big red exclamation mark next to them and won't run. It says that it can't find the jar file in the library. When I look in the library's bin folder there is no jar file there. I don't really know what I am doing wrong. I am not extracting the file from github properly? Do I have to create my own jar file from the library? I remember having this problem before with another library I tried to use. Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers, Sam.
PS this is the library I am trying to use https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting a library project from github you should set it a "isLibrary" from `properties->android` and then use it as library in your project also from `properties->android`

I hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. It was actually an issue of updating my android sdk for eclipse (+/- eclipse) - I had not updated it since the release of in app payments and I think it did not have the right compatibility libraries or something like that. Seems to work now.